# Reading variables of a function

Tags: php, reflection, scope

I have a function with some code in it, but I'm not allowed to touch it (ie: add more code). Is there a way in PHP to get variables defined in that function?

Thank you for helping...

Ok, I've not been very clear. Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
$hello(function() {
    $a = "this is a variable!";
});
```

I want this code to serve a file (a view), capable of reading variable $a.

I've recently tried playing around with php's reflection and found a way to extract static variables.... don't think there's a way for all other variables, but I'll keep searching.

```
$obj = new ReflectionFunction($my_closure); 
print_r($obj->getStaticVariables());
```

Comment: What that function do and why do you want to get variables?

Comment: There definitely isn't enough information in this question. What does the function look like, but more importantly: /why/ would you want to "add variables" to that function?

Comment: It's a callback function and I'm executing it this way:

$a["callback"]();

I would like to serve a file which is capable to read variables inside this callback.

Comment: That's still pretty difficult to understand. Be more specific please. Show some code. Use more words. Dont assume we know what you are talking about. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6030346/edit) please.

Comment: Hm, `$hello(function() { $a = "this is a variable!";});` is no valid PHP code. Maybe you're mixing up jQuery and PHP here?

Comment: @Jürgen: With 5.3 PHP introduces Closures. As long as `$hello` is a valid callback this is valid PHP-code.

Comment: @KingCrunch: argl, that happens when you test code in 5.2.x ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables defined in the function will only be visible within the scope of the function and so have no relevance to any other code on your site.